# Unable to kill child process in ProcessPool: RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

I'm trying to simulate what happens when I attempt to kill a child process.  I'm on Python 3.9.0. This is is a "stepping stone" attempt to understand the [bug report here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/75670).

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import asyncio
import os
import signal
import sys
import time


def background_task():
    print(f"Running background task {os.getpid()}", file=sys.stderr)
    time.sleep(15)
    print("Exiting background task", file=sys.stderr)


async def task():
    print("Running task")

    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    with executor:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        try:
            await loop.run_in_executor(executor, background_task)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("Cancelling task 1", file=sys.stderr)

            try:
                await asyncio.sleep(15)
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                print("Cancelling task 2", file=sys.stderr)
                raise

            raise
    print("done task ")

def main():
    def terminate(coro):
        print(f"Terminating {os.getpid()}")
        coro.cancel()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t = asyncio.ensure_future(task())
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, terminate, t)

    try:
        print(f"Running {os.getpid()}", file=sys.stderr)
        loop.run_until_complete(t)
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
Running 7781
Running task
Running background task 7783
```

Now, I do:

```
kill -s SIGTERM 7783
```

I get:

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<task() running at /Users/me/test_prophet/wtf.py:23> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/futures.py:384, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x1010e7dc0>()]>>
```

Why might this be happening?